# Carcassonne - taking control of a city

Tags: carcassonne

We have just started playing and have the river expansion game.

I had hoped to try to take control over a city by placing a last wall piece and placing a meeple.  This was a U shaped piece and no tiles where in the interior city....just walls.  I was told I could not because it joined other walls of the city and was an end piece.  I'm confused as to how one would take over a city and gain all the points.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you add a photo and/or diagram of the board situation?

Comment: Are you asking about taking control of a city from another player? Or just taking control of an empty city using the last tile?

Comment: Has anyone sufficiently answered your question?  If yes, please select the answer.  If no, how can we better answer your question?

Answer (score 22):

## Basic Rules:

On your turn you place a tile.  After placing the tile you can place your meeple onto any uncontrolled feature on that tile.  After placing meeples, all completed features are scored.

## Assuming that you are trying to gain some control of a controlled city

Let's assume the situation is this:
[image]

In the situation that you have presented you have placed your tile to close a city.  Once that tile is placed, looking at the board, it is already controlled by another meeple, therefore you cannot place a meeple there.

[image]

To take some control of a city requires two moves.  The first is to place a tile that is not connected to the city that you want to control, separated by a single tile space from the city and place a meeple on that city.  On a later turn, play a tile that connects the main city to the small city you created on the previous tile.
[image]

This would give blue and red equal control, splitting the points. To take complete control would require you to perform this step again.  (Or a big meeple from Inns and Cathedrals)

## Assuming that the feature is uncontrolled.

Place the tile.  The city is uncontrolled, so place a meeple.  Score the completed city.

[image]

Comment: Slightly pedantically: I wouldn't say blue has "taken control" of the city in your second example - there is one red meeple and one blue meeple in the city, so the points are shared. You have to repeat the trick to get control of the city (modulo big meeples).

Comment: @PhilipKendall Pedantic or not, your criticism is fair. Does my edit satisfy you? :)

Answer (score 3):

The order of actions in a turn is as follows:

1. Place tile
2. Place follower
3. Determine and score completed structures

So your city is not completed until after you've had a chance to place a follower onto it. So in your example, you were right.

Comment: That is only true if no other players had followers in the now completed city.

Comment: @bwarner The question as I read it, is about order of events: can I place a follower on a structure if that tile completes the structure. Bringing in other base rules makes for an unnecessarily long answer.